# Can I use this code to set the height of two elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I want to set both `#map_canvas` and `#content`'s height, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
$(['#map_canvas','#content']).css("height", ($(window).height()-270 + "px"));
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#map_canvas, #content').height(window.height-270);
```

I do something similar with google earth integration on a current project...

Answer (score 0):

Try (you kinda have extra parentesis in there):

`$(['#map_canvas','#content']).css("height", $(window).height()-270 + "px");`

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#map_canvas,#content").css("height", (jQuery(window).height() - 270 ) + "px");
```